# /dev/tcp not found

Tags: bash, tcp

When I try to run the following command:

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n" | /dev/tcp/74.125.225.19/80
```

I get the following error message:

```
bash: /dev/tcp/74.125.225.19/80: No such file or directory
```

The following command works perfectly, so the problem involves how I'm using `/dev/tcp`:

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n" | nc 74.125.225.19 80
```

I'm in Ubuntu 13.04, so the capability *should* be on my system. What am I doing wrong? What are the rules for using `/dev/tcp` properly?

Comment: Here's a [working http request code example using /dev/tcp](http://askubuntu.com/a/525550/3712)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to use it in [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections):

> Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in
>   redirections, as described in the following table:
>
> ...
>
> /dev/tcp/host/port
>
> If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port is an
>   integer port number or service name, Bash attempts to open the
>   corresponding TCP socket.

So:

```
printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n" > /dev/tcp/74.125.225.19/80
```

is the right way to use it.

When you used `/dev/tcp/74.125.225.19/80` in a pipe, `bash` attempted to run a command named `/dev/tcp/74.125.225.19/80` and reported an error because that file didn't exist.

---

The ability to handle `/dev/tcp/host/port` and `/dev/udp/host/port` in redirection was added to `bash` in version 2.04.

You need to compiled `bash` with `--enable-net-redirections` option.

Comment: I see, so `/dev/tcp` is treated as a "file" and not a script.

Comment: This is **not** a factual answer for macOS.